# How to make change event work for radiobutton for html added with replaceWith

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I managed to get the change event firing for a radiobutton. However I now needed it to work for html where the radiobutton is added to the markup with replaceWith.

So it is added to my markup with:

```
$(this).replaceWith('<input type="radio" name="variety" value="null" id="myradio" />');
```

So, the code I have for catching the change event is:

```
$('#myradio').change(function () {
        alert("Hello");
    });
```

So does anyone know how I would make this work given the radio button is now added to the page after the initial page load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (jQuery 1.7+) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (jQuery 1.4.3+) to subscribe to the change event in order to account for dynamically added elements.

For example:

```
$('#myradio').live('change', handler);                // jQuery 1.3+

$(document).delegate('#myradio', 'change', handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+

$(document).on('change', '#myradio', handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

It's also important to point out that it is not necessary to place this subscription inside a `document.ready` callback.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
$('body').on('change', '#myradio', function () {
    alert("Hello");
});
```

If you know beforehand the element in which you'll be putting the radiobutton, you should change the 'body' selector to match that element for performance.

Answer (score 0):

either:

- use jQuery `on` to a parent

  ```
  <div id="container">
      <!--replaceable elements-->
  </div>

  //this will take effect on current and future children
  $('#container').on('change','targetSelector',function(){
      alert("Hello");
  });
  ```
- or bind directly to the new element

  ```
  function func(){
      alert("Hello");
  }

  var newEl = $('<input type="radio" name="variety" value="null" id="myradiobutton" />');
  newEl.change(func);
  $(this).replaceWith(newEl);
  ```

i prefer the first one though, for performance and clean code.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the radio button, add the change event, then replace `this` with the radio button.

```
var $radio = $('<input type="radio" name="variety" value="null" id="myradio" />');
$radio.change(function () {
    alert("Hello");
});
$(this).replaceWith($radio);
```